# I'm facing problem with file handler in python while on online ide it worked perfectly

Tags: python, python-3.x

Same file handler not working on a file in the same script on offline python environment(3.7.1) while working fine on online ide.

I'm learning python from Chuck Severance course(py4e) and noticed this while working on the assignment which required me to read from a file and print its contents after capitalising each letter. Now to do this I have two methods available, one is using for loop and another is read() function. After running each one individually, I thought of running both in the same script but only one work. When I created a new file handler and run both in the same script using individual file handlers pointing the same file, it worked.Now,weird part is that in the online ide,both worked using the same file handler.SO,my doubt is that why are both different since python is same i.e. python 3. Why on my system,I'm unable to use the same file handler while it worked fine on online ide.

```
fname=input("Enter file name : ")
fh=open(fname)
for line in fh:
    print(line.rstrip().upper())

print("****Using read()****")
fdata=fh.read()
print(fdata.rstrip().upper())
```

Expected : Same output after "****Using read()****"
Actual:Nothing after "****Using read()****"

Comment: You are probably mistaken in your memory of what worked. `for line in fh` will iterate to the end of the file. Trying to then `read` from the file will produce nothing. You need to either `open` the file again, or `seek` back to the beginning: `fh.seek(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgetting to read the file again after reading it for the first time.

After your first loop, cursor goes to end of the file (EOF) and as you are not opening the file again it does not read anything, as the cursor is at EOF.

Best practice is to close the file after reading it and open again.
correct code is

```
fname=input("Enter file name : ")
fh=open(fname)
for line in fh:
    print(line.rstrip().upper())
fh.close()

print("****Using read()****")
fh=open(fname)
fdata=fh.read()
print(fdata.rstrip().upper())
fh.close()
```

Comment: Okay, now I got it why new file handler worked. Also, my code worked correctly on online ide that means the ide automatically moves to the start of the file or closes the file as soon as the line executed.Right?

Comment: which online ide are you using?

Comment: It was a custom ide provided by the professor for the course.